# Save RSS feed in variable (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

How can I save an RSS feed in variable? The feed would be just an IP address of stream, so I wouldn't have to update app every time when IP changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial explains all the detail information step by step. That might be very useful not only the question that you have, but also question you might have in the future

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/

Comment: Hi, I get that but after this: NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://somesite.com/rss_feed.xml"]; how can I set a value of title(RSS title) to a variable called var_a?